# Dual monitors - HDMI Monitor doesn't display top menu bar

Tags: nvidia, multiple-monitors, resolution, hdmi

I have an Ubuntu 14.04.1 desktop that I recently built and I'm having issues getting my HDMI monitor to display correctly. I also have a DVI monitor that I've been using that I haven't had any trouble with.

It's recognized and seems to be working (I can drag windows between the two displays and work on both):

[image]

and while it looks like everything is working just fine from these screenshots, I can't actually see the top menu bar on the second, HDMI monitor. Anything selected in orange (and a bit below the window too) I can't actually see.

It's definitely there, because I can click the menus (part of which show up visible to me) - the top menu bar doesn't actually show up.

Here's the output from `xrandr`, if that helps any:

```
~$ xrandr
Screen 0: minimum 8 x 8, current 2560 x 1024, maximum 16384 x 16384
DVI-I-0 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
DVI-I-1 connected primary 1280x1024+0+0 (normal left inverted right x axis y axis) 338mm x 270mm
   1280x1024      60.0*+
   1152x864       75.0  
   1024x768       75.0     70.1     60.0  
   800x600        75.0     72.2     60.3     56.2  
   640x480        75.0     72.8     59.9  
DP-0 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
HDMI-0 connected 1280x720+1280+178 (normal left inverted right x axis y axis) 440mm x 250mm
   1280x720       60.0*+   59.9  
   1920x1080      59.9     60.1     60.0  
   1440x480       60.1  
   1360x768       60.0  
   1280x768       60.0  
   1024x768       60.0  
   800x600        60.3  
   720x480        59.9     60.1  
   640x480        59.9     59.9  
DP-1 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
```

Is this an issue with my GPU, drivers, or my screen? Could it be the different sizes/aspect ratio that they have in comparison to each-other?

I've got a EVGA GeForce GTX 750 Ti FTW GPU with the NVIDIA proprietary Linux x86_64 334.21 drivers.

Monitors - first one is an NEC MultiSync LCD1770NX and the second (HDMI, the one I'm having issues with) is a Coby 15" - not sure the full name. As a side note, the fact that Ubuntu is recognizing it as a 20", when it's actually a 15", might be contributing to this issue.

**Edit**:

So, after a bit more searching around on the internets, I found a guide that pointed me to look into the NVIDIA X Server Settings.

While the guide didn't actually help me specifically, it did help me find a setting, Underscan, that I tweaked until the display was showing to top bar. However, there is still some on the bottom of the screen that isn't visible.

This makes me think that this is a resolution issue - I'm going to try and find the native res for this screen.

Comment: I have an Intel HD 4000 and dual monitor setup is Ok here. But if I use the HDMI to my TV, I have similar problem: top screen is out of view. Hint: what is the resolution used by the 2nd screen in its menu from hardware button on the screen. is it the 1280x720 ? may be that's because it's not its  default reoslution

Comment: @solsTiCe Good idea. I'll check that.

Comment: @solsTiCe I can't actually see any default resolution listed on the actual device or in any of the menus. This isn't actually a TV I bought, it was given to me, so I'd have to go digging and find the box to get the default resolution - that might actually be the issue though!

Answer (score 1):

Kinda stupid that I can't just comment,  but whatever. It might be an overscan problem.  There should be a 'just scan'  option on your TV. If not, it might be an overscanning problem with Ubuntu, which can be set in xorg config settings. Does your mouse 'hit' the top of the screen? Or does it go past the top?

Comment: Well, I'll give you an upvote to help with the commenting :) As for the overscan, that actually was something I tried out - and it fixed it so I can see the top menu bar. However, still can't see some of the bottom of the screen.

Comment: Hmm, can you adjust the monitor display to move picture up, down, left or right? If it's just a TV, then probably not. Also,  like solsTiCe said,  it might not be the native resolution,  causing it to cut it off.  Does it look fuzzy?

Comment: Nope, it's just a 15" LCD TV, no picture adjustment option :(

Comment: Can you check the default resolution?

Comment: If you look on the back of the color and tell me the model number, I could help a lot more

Comment: xrandr says that it supports 1920x1080 resltion. Have you tried to use it ?

Comment: Xrandr is often wrong